# Selecting data from a MySQL table using condition from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two MySQL table HouseHold and UserProfile. Both tables contain the columns HouseHoldID. I want to select all rows from HouseHold Table where HouseHoldID in both tables are equal. How cani do that? I am using the following code

```
select * from Household where Household.HouseholdID = UserProfile.HouseholdID
```

But its not giving anything rather showing error.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please read & understand about SQL JOIN

Comment: What you have tried ? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm please read this link

Comment: Yes I am clarified about the matter now. I was confused on the use of JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN`:

```
select * from Household
JOIN UserProfile
ON UserProfile.HouseholdID=Household.HouseholdID
```

Or with an `EXISTS`:

```
select * from Household
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT NULL
   FROM UserProfile
   WHERE UserProfile.HouseholdID=Household.HouseholdID
)
```

Or with an `IN`:

```
select * from Household
WHERE Household.HouseholdID IN 
(
   SELECT UserProfile.HouseholdID
   FROM UserProfile
)
```

Or the old way with the from statement

```
select * from Household, UserProfile
WHERE UserProfile.HouseholdID=Household.HouseholdID
```

It kinda depends on what data you want

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the idea

Answer (score 1):

You have to select from two table 
Like the following way:

```
select * from Household, UserProfile where Household.HouseholdID = UserProfile.HouseholdID
```

Or Use **Join**

```
select * from Household h
JOIN UserProfile u
ON u.HouseholdID=h.HouseholdID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the UserProfile table as well

```
select * from Household h JOIN UserProfile u ON h.HouseholdID = u.HouseholdID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT A.* FROM Household A INNER JOIN UserProfile B ON A.HouseholdID = B.HouseholdID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` the tables. Try this:

```
select * from 
Household h JOIN
UserProfile u ON u.HouseholdID =h.HouseholdID
```

Learn more about joins [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the SQL language has very neat way to select records from both tables by given criteria, it is called **JOIN**:

```
SELECT H.*, U.* FROM Household H 
INNER JOIN UserProfile U ON U.HouseholdID = H.HouseholdID
```